# Save User-Created views (e.g. buttons and text views) to be restored when using the app again

Tags: android, android-studio

My Activity has 6 default CardViews, each cardview contains a Constraint layout and the constraint layout contains a couple of Text views
my problem is, I wanted to add an "ADD" which would take you through some steps and eventually create a new cardview, but how would I save that view created by the user so when they close the app and enter again it would still be there? (Users could add multiple cardviews)

- I'm familiar with SharedPreferences but i don't think it would be possible in this case because it requires me to save the data in a declared string and the user simply doesn't have access to that

What i want to do is something similar to Alarm apps, when you can add multiple alarms, delete alarms etc and it would be there even if you restart the Alarm app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is not saving the `view` itself, but rather save info or state of each object after user modifies it. And you are right about `SharedPreferences`, it wouldn't be the best option for this...

So, I would recommend two things:

1. Saving & getting your Cardviews data should be from a custom class (for ex: `Alarm`) that has properties.

   ```
   package my.app.example;

   class Alarm{
    long time;
    boolean isOn;
    String label;

    public Alarm(long time, boolean isOn, String label){
        this .time = time;
        this .isOn = isOn;
        this .label = label;
    }
   }
   ```

And you can use it as follows:

```
long timeFromDatabase = ...;//get time value from database
boolean isOnFromDatabase= ...;//get isOn value from database
String labelFromDatabase= ...;//get label value from database

Alarm alarm1 = new Alarm(timeFromDatabase, isOnFromDatabase, labelFromDatabase);
```

After, you can add each Alarm object to a List, and then pass it to your `Adapter`

2. A database (I recommend [`Sqlite`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite) or `Json`) to which you will save each Alarm data (time, isOn, ...)

**Remark** `Alarm` is just an example! Feel free to use whatever name and properties that suit your project

See this tutorial it's way is similar to what I suggested: https://www.javatpoint.com/android-sqlite-tutorial, he saves contacts to an sqlite offline database and get them later.

Comment: While searching, I found out about Firebase (I think it and the databases you recommended are similar) but I'm still not sure how would that work out, like my app would save each object data on it and on start up it would go throw them and create each one?

Comment: Also I wanted to know, are referring to "alarmManager" as custom class? the reason why I'm trying to find another solution than databases is that my app would be more of an offline app, so I wanted to ask how does the Alarm app for example does that without databses?

Comment: - Sqlite database is an offline database that is saved to device internal storage, check this link https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite

Comment: No no, I didn't mean alarmManager, see my updated answer and the tutorial at the end

Comment: I read the update and I got the point. I have read more about sqlite by now, I will definitely check the tutorial you provided as well, thanks a lot.